# EventTransmitterPiggybacker.onFailure(EventTransmitterPiggybacker.java:68) when trying to invoke any worklight adapter Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Hey i'm creating android app which using worklight native api but i'm getting this Exception when there is connection error and i don't know how to handle it

```
 at com.worklight.location.internal.events.EventTransmitterPiggybacker.onFailure(EventTransmitterPiggybacker.java:68)
    09-21 14:09:44.472 20167-20285/cloudappers.com.rta_ca E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.processFailureResponse(WLRequest.java:597)
    09-21 14:09:44.472 20167-20285/cloudappers.com.rta_ca E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java:194)
    09-21 14:09:44.472 20167-20285/cloudappers.com.rta_ca E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.worklight.wlclient.InternalRequestSender.run(AsynchronousRequestSender.java:138)
    09-21 14:09:44.472 20167-20285/cloudappers.com.rta_ca E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    09-21 14:09:44.472 20167-20285/cloudappers.com.rta_ca E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Comment: You'll need to do better than that. What is your worklight version and build number. Provide actual code that can be debugged (an app...), explain what you're doing in your app in general and when it is failing.

Comment: wlPlatformVersion = 6.1.0.02.20150701-2210

Comment: Hey @IdanAdar this happen everytime  I call any adapter

Comment: Are you going to provide the requested information?

Comment: Can you please provide further details for the Exception? What is the actual exception (please include line number). Thank you.

Comment: @Tony, Waiting to hear back from you.

Comment: @Tony, Why are you not replying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that this exception is a timeout exception 
so i solved this issue by increasing the timeout

```
WLRequestOptions options = new WLRequestOptions();
    options.setTimeout(60000);
```

i know this is not the solution which will solve the exception permanently but at least it never happens again